# Can we access hibernate session from separate deployed application?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have one java stand alone application Where I have implemented **Hibernate session factory**.
Now I want that **session factory's session** to retrieve data or alter/save data from other application which is not
deployed on the same server where that java standalone application is deployed.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: When you say data, you mean Entities ?

Comment: Not sure the operating system would allow this sort of IPC until both the applications store the data in one common location, which can be directly accessed.

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368802/how-can-i-call-a-method-in-an-object-from-outside-the-jvm

Comment: Also, your words Standalone application deployed on server confuse me. Either there is a Standalone app, which user installs or webapp which user consumes from browser. What is a Standalone app which is not on same server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to get and use a session instance outside of the JVM where it was created and the environment, which is resopnsible for it's lifecycle, like with any other java class instance.

The only way to achieve remote session access, is to use some kind of remote service implementation, wich will give you some API for data access and modification. It could be Web Services, CORBA, JMS, RMI or something else.