# Shell script calling non-main method of running java program

Tags: java, bash, shell

I have developed a shell script, which calls main method of a java program `RHEL` environment.

Shell script ( say `app.sh`) have multiple options on the lines of `tomcat.sh`

`start:` It will start a java program by calling main method

`stop:` It will get running process id and kill the process

I have already implemented `start` and `stop` command and looking forward to implement pause command.

`pause:` ***This option should get the pid of running java application and call a non-Main method***.

I don't have issues to get the process id. ***But can I invoke non-Main method of java program from running process id?***

**EDIT:**

[How can I call a method in an object from outside the JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368802/how-can-i-call-a-method-in-an-object-from-outside-the-jvm) question offer solutions in different technologies but I can't move to different technology except using shell script.

Comment: I think you can't do that. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411972/calling-java-methods-from-shell-scripts) for more info.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368802/how-can-i-call-a-method-in-an-object-from-outside-the-jvm

Comment: I have checked that question. But I am looking to call non-main method of existing process rather than calling new main method of new process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution would be like the following:

1. Create a service as usually.
2. The service exposes a number of methods via [JMX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javamanagement-140525.html) or simply by listening a TCP/unix-domain socket for a limited set of known commands.
3. When there's a need to control, the service a dedicated process (presumably, an utility written in Java, separately from the service), issues required commands via a designated command channel.

The [SO question that I mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368802/how-can-i-call-a-method-in-an-object-from-outside-the-jvm) contains all necessary technical details. Actually all credits should be given there, I'm just rearranging their words.

Alternatively in Unix-like systems, including Linux you may send a SIGSTOP signal for a given pid (`kill -STOP <pid>`), and the JVM will be stopped unconditionally until SIGCONT is received (`kill -CONT <pid>`). But I guess it'd be an overwhelmingly brutal solution. Likely you will lose all opened connections etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have found one solution to get rid of limitation of she'll script calling only main method of a program.

1. RMI URL of program A is persisted in database or file system.
2. Program B reads that RMI URL.
3. Start option of script  calls main method of program A. Pause option of script  calls main method of program B.
4. Program B calls remote method of Program A.

One more solution: call a jsp page, which invokes remote method on Program A by using wget command from script in pause option.